# Отмена задачи в Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

В коде tasks.py Есть задача:

```
def bar2(self, request):
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    for i in range(7):
        if self.is_aborted():
            return 'Таск остановлен!'
        username = request['request']
        entry_list = Playlist.objects.values_list('url', flat=True).filter(author = User.objects.get(username = username))
        print(entry_list)

    task_id = self.request.id
    print('Таск айди ' + str(task_id))
    return task_id
```

Есть задача по её отмене:

```
@shared_task
def cancel_task(task_id):
    ben = task_id
    task = bar2.AsyncResult(ben)
    if task.state in ['PENDING', 'STARTED', 'RETRYING', 'PROGRESS']:
        task.revoke()
        return 'Задача отменена'
    else:
        return 'Невозможно отменить задачу в текущем состоянии'
```

В views.py код выглядит следующим образом:

```
def pars1(request):
    zen = request.user.username
    task = bar2.delay({'request': str(zen)})
    request.session['b'] = task.task_id
    return redirect(reverse('lost'))


def parstimeoff(request):
    ben = request.session['b']
    cancel_task.delay(ben)
    return redirect(reverse('lost'))
```

Запускаю задачу bar2(), потом её отмену cancel_task()

При срабатывании кода отмены пишет что задача отменена, но на самом деле она не отменена, в чем причина и как её отменить?

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты совершаешь, revoke() к задаче она отменяется, но отменяется любопытным образом.
Она помечается как отмененная для всех воркеров, но не удаляется сразу, чтобы не было поиск O(n) при каждом удалении.
Когда воркер встречает такую помеченную задачу, он сам ее откидывает и не выполняет.
Что касается удаления её, я вот сейчас сам пытаюсь найти отвтет, как работает в принципе удаление в celery. В документации написано, что это происходит автоматически из памяти.